# Why android camera preview need a surfaceView?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Call **startPreview()** to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture. Without a surface, the camera will be unable to start the preview.

What did android api do to the surface view ?

Why setPreviewSurface(Surface surface) must be called before startPreview() ?

I just got the data via On data callback, not from a surface view.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a picture usually requires that your users see a preview of their subject before clicking the shutter. To do so, you can use a [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) to draw previews of what the camera sensor is picking up.

You will get more information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

Comment: Actually i got data from onData callback,  do something such as face detect, then use openGL to render the modified data on a surface,  nothing related to the surface Texture in camera. why mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mCameraTexture) must be called before startPreview()